# Why does it output Nan when the timer is output in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I made a reverse timer that takes its values from `querySelectorAll` there may be several of them so I put a loop that works fine but only in the console as soon as I want to output in HTML outputs Nan

I get several dates from classes

```
 let date_reg_end = document.querySelectorAll(".time1");
```

I calculate the timer itself and output it

```js
let countDownDate = setInterval(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < date_reg_end.length; i++) {
    var t = Date.parse(date_reg_end[i].innerHTML) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    // date_reg_end[i].innerText = days+'d'+hours+'h'+minutes+'m';
    // console.log(days+'d'+hours+'h'+minutes+'m');
  }

}, 1000);
```

if I output only `console.log(days+ ' d '+hours+ 'h'+minutes+ 'm');` it outputs everything as it should calculate everything as it should

if I output `date_reg_end[i]` to html `innerText = days+ 'd'+hours+ 'h'+minutes+ 'm'` then it works once and then `NaN`

[image]

Comment: Can you complete the example in the question to be a runnable demonstration?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML in a [mcve]

Comment: `days+'d'+hours+'h'+minutes+'m'` is not parseable as a date. Instead use a data-attribute. After first time, you have an invalid date string in your date_regs

Comment: The *probable* reason is that your date strings (one or more of them) are not valid. When that happens, the Date instance will be invalid and all of the getters will return `NaN`.

Comment: if I go to the console everything works fine both dates are calculated and change their value but only in the console as soon as I output in html then Nan

Comment: innerText and InnerHTML don't work

Comment: show us your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use data attribute instead of innerHTML

`days+'d'+hours+'h'+minutes+'m'` is not parse-able as a date.

After first time, you have an invalid date string in your date_regs

Instead use a data-attribute:

```js
const date_reg_end = document.querySelectorAll(".time");
let countDownDate = setInterval(function() {

  for (let i = 0; i < date_reg_end.length; i++) {
    const end = date_reg_end[i].dataset.time;
    const t = Date.parse(end) - Date.parse(new Date());
    const seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    const hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    const days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    date_reg_end[i].innerText = days+'d'+hours+'h'+minutes+'m'+seconds+'s until '+end;
    // console.log(days+'d'+hours+'h'+minutes+'m');
  }

}, 1000);
```

```html
<span class="time" data-time="2020/12/17 12:33"></span><hr/>
<span class="time" data-time="2021/07/17 15:00"></span>
```

Comment: but he is not parsing Date in that format. He swaps it to that kind of format. We don't know what kind of format is grabbed by `innerHTML`,

Comment: @sonic Yes we do. `date_reg_end = document.querySelectorAll(".time1");` and `Date.parse(date_reg_end[i].innerHTML)` and `date_reg_end[i].innerText = days+'d'+hours+'h'+minutes+'m';`

Comment: Whatever that is, it is not parsable

Comment: I thought that `date_reg_end[i]` will change just one element

Comment: Or you think there is some HTML that will be parsed by Date.parse in a different manner?

Comment: if this is in HTML : "2020/12/17 12:33". Won't it parse it ?

Comment: @sonic Yes, but ONLY the first time!!! That is his problem

Comment: @sonic My answer: `After first time, you have an invalid date string in your date_regs`

Comment: hahah, its not my point. He is looping so everytime he is getting next element. So he has never grabbed element that was updated

Comment: Yes he does that in the next second! THEN he gets NaN - setInterval is a loop too

Comment: Every second he loops over all .time elements and updates them. First time ok, a second later not ok

Comment: Ok I get it. I just completly ignored that it is in `setInterval` function